# Specify Collation in Docker installation

Tags: sql-server, docker, collation, sql-server-collation

I've used this [guide](https://www.klokocka.info/?p=1771) to install [sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver) on [docker](/questions/tagged/docker). However, the default collation it sets up is not the one I require. Is there a way to specify the desired collation during the installation process without having to change it afterwards? Thanks.

I don't know how to specify the collation I want: SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP850_CI_AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server in Docker and Linux can be configured using [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-environment-variables?view=sql-server-ver16). Use `MSSQL_COLLATION` to specify the desired collation:

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" \
    -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>"
    -e "MSSQL_COLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP850_CI_AS" \
    -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```